# Android saving file to cache directory

Tags: android, xml-serialization, android-xml, java-io, android-file

I am trying to do something simple like save a file to a cache directory in Android and I am having a lot of problems. I am using Simple serializer to write out my file into xml.

Here is my code:

```
public void testWrite(ListDefinitions ld)
{
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();

    String fileName = "sampleExport.xml";
    try {
        File file = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        serializer.write(ld, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
09-18 00:35:06.229: W/System.err(4442): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.main/cache/sampleExport.xml: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `sampleExport.xml` is a directory rather than a file as you intended.

Comment: Thank you for response. How would I go about making it a file? I basically want to write a temp file to cache dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you created directory before with wrong call. Try to clean app data in settings.

Comment: Actually, that was it! Thank you!